# Is there a way to test a range of numbers on fiddler to add certain item to cart?

Tags: php, http, magento, fiddler

I don't know too much about programming but I was wondering if there was a way to 'bruteforce', I guess, the product IDs to find the one I am looking for on a website.

I am currently using Fiddler to add another item to cart and all that I need to figure out now is the product ID of the item that I actually want. This is the [link](http://www.nakedcph.com/commodity/4843-adidas-originals-naked-x-adidas-consortium-ultraboost-waves-pack) to it.

[image]

If you are wondering why I am doing this, it is because I want to add the item to the cart so that as soon as it releases I can click checkout and buy the item. This shoe is limited and will have a lot of people with bots trying to buy it and I am just trying to do it with this way.